# QT 5.3.2 - IMX6S segmentation fault

Tags: qt, embedded-linux

successfully build and cross compile Qt 5.3.2 for target IMX6S.
simple aml app works fine on host machine(ubuntu 12.04), but giving following error for IMX6S board
error :- Segmentation fault.

## ./Hello -eglfs

QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QEglFSImx6Hooks will set environment variable FB_MULTI_BUFFER=2 to enable double buffering and vsync.
 If this is not desired, you can override this via: export QT_EGLFS_IMX6_NO_FB_MULTI_BUFFER=1
Segmentation fault

.................................

not getting any idea why getting this err happening, any help for this issue highly appreciated.

Comment: simple *QT/qml app works fine on host machine(ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: Why don't you debug it?

Comment: Hi @sashoalm, thanx for your reply. I am very much new to Qt-Embedded  and not handy with all this stuff. Now I am referring following links :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296217/segmentation-fault-while-running-qt-helloworld-on-embedded-system

http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Debugging.html#Remote-Debugging

but got stuck. not getting idea how to get over through this.